# Laravel Mix, a right way to install PhotoSwipe lib

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-mix, photoswipe

I try to include PhotoSwipe into my project. And the question how to right way to include all the lib files, JS, CSS and images.

I do something like this -

```
yarn add photoswipe
```

Than at bottom of esources/assets/js/bootstrap.js I add

```
window.PhotoSwipe = require('photoswipe');
```

But I also need include extra JS (photoswipe-ui-default.js) not described in package.json, don't sure is this a correct way?

```
mix.copy('node_modules/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-ui-default.js', 'public/js');

<script src="{{ asset('js/photoswipe-ui-default.js') }}" defer></script>
```

And also the question how to include skin files?

Answer (score 2):

I never a fan of using mix.copy script or css feel very hacky so what I did was

in bootstrap.js

```
window.PhotoSwipe = require('photoswipe');
window.PhotoSwipeUI_Default = require('./../../node_modules/photoswipe/src/js/ui/photoswipe-ui-default.js');
```

in app.scss

```
@import "~photoswipe/src/css/main";
@import "~photoswipe/src/css/default-skin/default-skin";
```

when using it

```
new window.PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, window.PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
```

hope its help =D